# How to test that a form object includes a Form property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, reform

I have a form object that looks like this:

```
class LeaderForm < UserForm
  feature Reform::Form::MultiParameterAttributes

  property :title
  property :gender
  property :phone_number
  property :date_of_birth, multi_params: true

  property :address, form: AddressForm # need to test this line

  validates :title, :gender, :phone_number, :date_of_birth, presence: true
end
```

How do I write a feature spec to test whether the `AddressForm` is present?

I already have a working spec to test the other "properties" (title, gender, etc.)

I've tried something like

```
it 'must have the address form present' do
  expect(form.address).to include(AddressForm)
end
```

The output of which is

```
  1) LeaderForm must have the address form present
       Failure/Error: expect(form.address).to include(AddressForm)

         expected #<AddressForm:0x007f89231c3280 @fields={"address1" => nil, "address2" => nil, "address3" => nil, "city" => ni...odel::Errors:0x007f89231c2b50 @base=#<AddressForm:0x007f89231c3280 ...>, @messages={}, @details={}>> to include AddressForm, but it does not respond to `include?`
         Diff:
         @@ -1,2 +1,41 @@
         -[AddressForm]
         +#<AddressForm:0x007f89231c3280
         + @_changes={},
         + @errors=
         +  #<Reform::Form::ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f89231c2b50
         +   @base=#<AddressForm:0x007f89231c3280 ...>,
         +   @details={},
         +   @messages={}>,
         + @fields=
         +  {"address1"=>nil,
         +   "address2"=>nil,
         +   "address3"=>nil,
         +   "city"=>nil,
         +   "postal_code"=>nil,
         +   "country"=>nil},
```

Which seems to me like it's almost there but not quite.

I am very new to RSpec in general so sorry if I haven't provided enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `be_a`:

```
it 'must have the address form present' do
  expect(form.address).to be_a(AddressForm)
end
```

RSpec maps an unknown matcher beginning with `be_`, like `be_foo`, to a method like `is_foo?`. You could also write (less nicely)

```
it 'must have the address form present' do
  expect(form.address.is_a? AddressForm).to be true
end
```